# logout using useContext() and navigate to login page after successful logout // react-router-dom v6.8.2 //react.js netflix clone {new to react}

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-context, logout

there is a logout button in dropdown menu and Logout.jsx is called as component in dropdown menu under topbar component. i checked with console.log ; all calls are made, localstorage "user" is cleared but yet navigate to login, doesn't get executed somehow.

Logout.jsx

```
import { useContext, useEffect, useState} from "react";
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { logout} from "../../context/authContext/ApiCalls";
import { logoutInitiate } from "../../context/authContext/AuthAction";
import { AuthContext } from "../../context/authContext/AuthContext";

export default function Logout() {
  const { isFetching , dispatch } = useContext(AuthContext);
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleLogout = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    navigate("/login");
   logoutInitiate(dispatch);
  };
   
  return (
    <div className="options">
        <Link to="/login">
            <span onClick={handleLogout} disabled={isFetching}>Logout</span>
        </Link> 
    </div>
  )
}
```

AuthContext.js

```
import AuthReducer from "./AuthReducer";
import {createContext, useEffect, useReducer } from "react";

const INITIAL_STATE = {
    user: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")) || null,
    isFetching:false,
    error:false
};

export const AuthContext = createContext(INITIAL_STATE);

export const AuthContextProvider = ({children}) => {
    const [state,dispatch] = useReducer(AuthReducer, INITIAL_STATE);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(state.user))
    },[state.user])

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider 
         value={{
            user:state.user,
            isFetching: state.isFetching,
            error: state.error,
            dispatch
            }}
        >
          {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
};
```

AuthReducer.js:

```
const AuthReducer = (state,action) => {
    switch(action.type){
      case "LOGIN_START":
         return{
           user:null,
           isFetching:true,
           error:false 
        };
        case "LOGIN_SUCCESS":
         return{
           user: action.payload,
           isFetching:false,
           error:false 
        };
        case "LOGIN_FAILURE":
         return{
           user:null,
           isFetching:false,
           error:true
        };
        case "LOGOUT":
         return{
           user:null,
           isFetching:false,
           error:false
        };
        default:
         return {...state};
    }
}

export default AuthReducer;
```

authAction.js:

```
export const loginStart = () => ({
  type: "LOGIN_START",
});

export const loginSuccess = (user) => ({
   type: "LOGIN_SUCCESS",
   payload: user, 
});

export const loginFailure = () => ({
    type: "LOGIN_FAILURE",
});

//logout
export const logoutInitiate = () => ({
  type: "LOGOUT",
});`
```

ApiCalls.js

```
import axios from "axios";
import { loginFailure, loginStart, loginSuccess ,logoutInitiate} from "./AuthAction";

export const login = async (user, dispatch) => {
  dispatch(loginStart);
  try{
    const res = await axios.post("auth/login", user);
    res.data.isAdmin && dispatch(loginSuccess(res.data))
  }catch(err){
    dispatch(loginFailure);
  }
};

export const logout = (dispatch) => {
  try{
    localStorage.removeItem("user") && dispatch(logoutInitiate()) ;
  }catch(err){
    console.log(err)
  }
};
```

App.js

```
import "./app.css"
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Navigate} from "react-router-dom";
import Layout from "./components/layout/Layout";
import Home from "./pages/home/Home";
import User from "./pages/user/User";
import UserList from "./pages/userList/UserList";
import NewUser from "./pages/newUser/NewUser";
import ProductList from "./pages/productList/ProductList";
import Product from "./pages/product/Product";
import NewProduct from "./pages/newProduct/NewProduct";
import Login from "./pages/login/Login";
import { useContext } from "react";
import { AuthContext } from "./context/authContext/AuthContext";


function App() {
  const {user} = useContext(AuthContext);
  //console.log(user)

  return (
  
    <Router>
      <Routes>
         {user && (
             <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
                <Route path="/" element={<Home/>} />
                <Route path="/users" element={<UserList/>} />
                <Route path="/user/:userId" element={<User/>} />
                <Route path="/newUser" element={<NewUser/>} />
                <Route path="/movies" element={<ProductList/>} />
                <Route path="/product/:productId" element={<Product/>} />
                <Route path="/newProduct" element={<NewProduct/>} />
              </Route>
          
          )}
        <Route path="/login" element={user ? <Navigate to="/"/> : <Login/>} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

- tried using navigate like `navigate("/otherpage")` => this worked somehow but it doesnt work when i use `navigate("/login")`
- tried using useState and useEffect to be able to call navigate in Logout.jsx
- i have looked into multiple posts related to same issue and their approaches hasn't solved my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it works now.I removed link in Logout.jsx  and changed

> logoutInitiate(dispatch);

with

> logout(dispatch); //as in ApiCall.js

after which navigate worked